# Enum class and pd DataFrame do not work together

Tags: python, pandas

this code:

```py
from enum import Enum
import pandas as pd

class Test(Enum):

    name_a = pd.DataFrame([
        [1,2,3]
    ], columns = ["a", "b", "c"])

    name_b = pd.DataFrame([
        [4,5,6]
    ], columns = ["d", "e", "f"])
```

gives the following error:
`ValueError: The truth value of a DataFrame is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().`

When I just have name_a or name_b in the class, it does work, though.
Don't understand what's going on there.

Thanks!

Comment: In order to get the error as described, I need to use the same list of strings for the column headers of both ```name_a``` and ```name_b```. Just a heads up if anybody cannot reproduce the error.

Comment: Try running this `bool(pd.DataFrame())` you will get the same error. This says to check for empty dataframe you need to call `df.empty()` not `bool(df)`. In enum code here, https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Lib/enum.py if you check then, `Enum` is built by `EnumType`, and there is `__bool__` dunder method is made to check for false or truth values, may be its failing there.

Comment: yeah i think enum is somehow confusing an attribute that dataframe with an internal one, or sth like that? @ChaddRobertson i dont fully get what you mean